# C# Linq select/join with custom return type

Tags: c#, linq, join, lambda

I have below linq sample:

```
List<FoodOrderItem> foodOrderItems = foodItemsWithPricesDbResult.ResultValue;

List<FoodOrderItem> orderItemsWithDiscounts= (from orderItem in order.Items
 join foodOrderItem in foodOrderItems
 on orderItem.FoodId equals foodOrderItem.Id
 select mergeOrderAndFoodInformation(foodOrderItem,orderItem)).ToList();

.
.
.
private static FoodOrderItem mergeOrderAndFoodInformation(FoodOrderItem foodOrderItem, OrderItem orderItem)
{
    foodOrderItem.DiscountValue = orderItem.DiscountValue;
    foodOrderItem.DiscountKind = orderItem.DiscountKind;
    foodOrderItem.CurrentOrderedCount = orderItem.Count;
    return foodOrderItem;
}
```

This `mergeOrderAndFoodInformation` function updates some fields of input `foodOrderItem` object and return updated foodOrderItem.

1- How can I write the `select mergeOrderAndFoodInformation(foodOrderItem,orderItem)` part in **inline** style if I don't want to use a function such `mergeOrderAndFoodInformation` to update and return result? I mean how can I change the `select mergeOrderAndFoodInformation(foodOrderItem,orderItem)` segment if I want to write the code without using an external function?

2- How can I write this linq query using Lambda notation?

P.S. Accept my apologies if keyword such as `inline` and `external` are not used correctly. I would be thankful if you correct me in case there are some mistakes.

Comment: Why do you want to inline the function? Are you hoping that it will get rid of errors that your query can't be translated to SQL?

Comment: @DStanley I want to learn the syntax, I know that above syntax is more readable. And what do you meant by `Are you hoping that it will get rid of errors that your query can't be translated to SQL?`? Can explain a bit?

Comment: If you aren't getting a similar error then don't worry about it. Often these questions arise because of errors translating the linq query to SQL, which inlining usually won't fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're modifying the objects in the source collection which is generally not a best practice when using Linq. It will require you to use lambda syntax to inline a function like so:

```
order.Items.Join(foodOrderItems, oi=>oi.FoodId, foi=>foi.Id, (oi, foi) => new {oi, foi})
           .Select(j => {
                          j.foi.DiscountValue = j.oi.DiscountValue;
                          j.foi.DiscountKind = j.oi.DiscountKind;
                          j.foi.CurrentOrderedCount = j.oi.Count;   
                          return j.foi;                         
                        })
            .ToList()
```

Note that `Join` is uglier (IMHO) in lambda syntax and the inline function doesn't buy you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<FoodOrderItem> foodOrderItems = foodItemsWithPricesDbResult.ResultValue;

    List<FoodOrderItem> orderItemsWithDiscounts = (from orderItem in order.Items
                                               join foodOrderItem in foodOrderItems
                                               on orderItem.FoodId equals foodOrderItem.Id
                                               select new FoodOrderItem
                                               {
                                                   DiscountValue = orderItem.DiscountValue,
                                                   DiscountKind = orderItem.DiscountKind,
                                                   CurrentOrderedCount = orderItem.Count
                                               }).ToList();
```

You can create the new object there itself.

Comment: This is creating new `FoodOrderItem` objects, not updating the properties of the original objects. I suspect that the original `FoodOtherItem` has _other_ properties that would get lost using this method.

Comment: As @DStanley noticed there are some other field which would be missed this way and I don't want to write it this way since by adding each new field to my objects in future I need to update all code which pass fields one by one.

Comment: @VSB sorry, I guess it's not possible since LINQ only provides new list to iterate over. It cannot do anything to the existing ones.